# return the first non repeating character in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

So I tried looking for this in the search but the closest I could come is a similar answer in several different languages, I would like to use Javascript to do it.

The problem is I have an arbitrary string that I would like to return the first non repeating character.  EX:  'aba' -> would return b
'aabcbd' -> would return c.
This is what I have so far, just a simple for loop to start.

```
var someString = 'aabcbd';



var firstNonRepeatedCharacter = function(string) {
for(var i = 0; i < someString.length; i++){

}
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w7F87/
Not sure where to go from here

Comment: The index of a non-repeating character will be odd and it will be different than the character before it.  That should be enough to get you through.

Comment: I don't understand, how would the index be odd? In my example c is in the third index but what if it was aabbcd instead which means it would be in the 4th index.?

Comment: He thinks it has to repeat the character before it

Comment: Are you familiar with map objects in JavaScript? Such as: `var charMap = {}; charMap['a'] = 0; charMap['b'] = 1;`? You could iterate through the input string, adding every char into a charMap: http://jsfiddle.net/w7F87/14/

Comment: @user3806863 - using the logic you outlined, in the sample in your comment the non-repeat would be 'd', the 6th letter at index 5.

Comment: 'aabbcbd'.replace(/(\w)\1/g,"")[0]; 'aabcbd'.replace(/(\w)\1/g,"")[0]; both work

Comment: I apologize if I came off as confusing. in the logic that I posted in the previous comment 'aabbcd', c is the first non-repeat character is it not?

Comment: @user3806863 - what do you mean be "non-repeating" do you mean that it does not repeat the character before it or that there is only one occurrence of the character in the string.  To my mind, non-repeating means that it does not occur in a pair.

Comment: do you mean unique or non-repeating, because you can do non-repeating quite a bit simpler/faster if perf matters...

Comment: when I say "non-repeating" I mean that there is only one occurence in the string. so aba would return b, acbcabd would return d etc.

Comment: I guess unique would be a better term, sorry about that

Comment: @user3806863 - sorry, then, I misunderstood.  I've added an O(n) solution to the problem as clarified.

Comment: Just FYI: you can even do that with regex granted the JS environment is ECMAScript 2018 compliant. `"abcab".match(/(\w)(?<!\1.+)(?!.*\1)/s)[1]` works in Chrome.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the `indexOf` method to find the non repeating character. If you look for the character in the string, it will be the first one found, and you won't find another after it:

```
function firstNonRepeatedCharacter(string) {
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    var c = string.charAt(i);
    if (string.indexOf(c) == i && string.indexOf(c, i + 1) == -1) {
      return c;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/Se4dD/

Comment: Both you and dave used the .charAt method, I am unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @user3806863: It gets the character at a specific index, `string.charAt(i)` does the same as `string[i]`, but it works in all browsers.

Comment: This solution, although it works, it's too inefficient. The time complexity for this solution is N-squared, because that `string.indexOf(c)` will have to go to the end of the string, each time, to see if it finds the char.
Given a string like this: "abcdeffedcba", .indexOf("a", 2) will go from the start of the string to the end of the end of the string. The same for each character (potentially).
A better solution is to create a character/integer map or cache. Itereate the string once to create the map and then once again to look for the char that has a value of 1.

Comment: function firstNonRepeatedCharacter(string) {
    const charCounter = {};
    for(let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        const char = string.charAt(i);
        if(!(char in charCounter)) {
            charCounter[char] = 0;
        }
        charCounter[char]++;
    }
    for(const c in charCounter) {
        if(charCounter[c] === 1) {
            return c;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

Comment: @JeremyThen: The `indexOf` method will actually never go to the end of the string until the first non-repeating character is found. Your idea of counting the characters is sound, but the implementation doesn't work. It relies on the object returning the properties in the order that you added them, which is not guaranteed. The function will return one of the non-repeating characters, but not necessarily the first one.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for the first occurrence of a letter that only occurs once, I would use another data structure to keep track of how many times each letter has been seen.  This would let you do it with an O(n) rather than an O(n<sup>2</sup>) solution, except that n in this case is the larger of the difference between the smallest and largest character code or the length of the string and so not directly comparable.

Note: an earlier version of this used `for-in` - which in practice turns out to be incredibly slow.  I've updated it to use the character codes as indexes to keep the look up as fast as possible.  What we really need is a hash table but given the small values of N and the small, relative speed up, it's probably not worth it for this problem.  In fact, you should prefer @Guffa's solution.  I'm including mine only because I ended up learning a lot from it.

```
function firstNonRepeatedCharacter(string) {
   var counts = {};
   var i, minCode = 999999, maxCode = -1;
   for (i = 0; i < string.length; ++i) {
        var letter = string.charAt(i);
        var letterCode = string.charCodeAt(i);
       if (letterCode < minCode) {
           minCode = letterCode;
       }
       if (letterCode > maxCode) {
           maxCode = letterCode;
       }
        var count = counts[letterCode];
        if (count) {
           count.count = count.count + 1;
        }
        else {
            counts[letterCode] = { letter: letter, count: 1, index: i };
        }
   }

    var smallestIndex = string.length;
    for (i = minCode; i <= maxCode; ++i) {
       var count = counts[i];
       if (count && count.count === 1 && count.index < smallestIndex) {
          smallestIndex = count.index;
       }
   }

    return smallestIndex < string.length ? string.charAt(smallestIndex) : '';
}
```

See fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/b2dE4/

Also a (slightly different than the comments) performance test at http://jsperf.com/24793051/2

Comment: @Xotic750 - that's very interesting.  I guess I was assuming that the object index would be an O(1) operation, but it's obviously not.  I wonder if converting it to an integer would improve that.

Comment: Using `counts = {}` may give a small improvement. It's worth noting how poor Opera is, but your code gets a big boost with that browser.

Comment: @Xotic750 - I've got an updated algorithm which runs significantly faster, though probably not on the small string test case. I had always assumed that `for-in` and the property index operations would be O(1) but apparently they're not.  Good learning opportunity.

Answer (score 3):

```
var firstNonRepeatedCharacter = function(string) {
  var chars = string.split('');
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (chars.filter(function(j) { 
                        return j == string.charAt(i); 
               }).length == 1) return string.charAt(i);
  }
};
```

So we create an array of all the characters, by splitting on anything.

Then, we loop through each character, and we filter the array we created, so we'll get an array of only those characters.  If the length is ever 1, we know we have a non-repeated character.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2FpZF/

Answer (score 2):

Two further possibilities, using ECMA5 array methods. Will return `undefined` if none exist.

Javascript

```
function firstNonRepeatedCharacter(string) {
    return string.split('').filter(function (character, index, obj) {
        return obj.indexOf(character) === obj.lastIndexOf(character);
    }).shift();
}

console.log(firstNonRepeatedCharacter('aabcbd'));
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/R3QD6/)

Or if you want a bit better performance, especially on longer strings.

Javascript

```
function firstNonRepeatedCharacter(string) {
    var first;

    string.split('').some(function (character, index, obj) {
        if(obj.indexOf(character) === obj.lastIndexOf(character)) {
            first = character;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });

    return first;
}

console.log(firstNonRepeatedCharacter('aabcbd'));
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Syf2f/)

Answer (score 2):

I came accross this while facing similar problem. Let me add my 2 lines.
What I did is a similar to the Guffa's answer. But using both `indexOf` method and `lastIndexOf`.

My mehod:

```
function nonRepeated(str) {
   for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      let j = str.charAt(i)
      if (str.indexOf(j) == str.lastIndexOf(j)) {
        return j;
      }
   }
   return null;
}

nonRepeated("aabcbd"); //c
```

Simply, `indexOf()` gets first occurrence of a character & `lastIndexOf()` gets the last occurrence. So when the first occurrence is also == the last occurence, it means there's just one the character.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Solution using Regex to replace all repeating characters and then returning the first character.

```js
function firstNonRepeat(str) {

   // Sorting str so that all repeating characters will come together & replacing it with empty string and taking first character using substr.

   var rsl = str.split('').sort().join('').replace(/(\w)\1+/g,'').substr(0,1);

   if(rsl) return rsl;

   else return 'All characters are repeated in ' + str;

}

console.log(firstNonRepeat('aaabcccdeeef'));
console.log(firstNonRepeat('aaacbdcee'));
console.log(firstNonRepeat('aabcbd'));
```

Comment: Nice solution without any loop, but Map solution is faster then this.

Comment: But this won't work with strings like `"fedbebcaac"` where your function will return `"d"` instead of `"f"`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, start your loop at 1, not 0. There is no point in checking the first character to see if its repeating, obviously it can't be.

Now, within your loop, you have someString[i] and someString[i - 1]. They are the current and previous characters.

if someString[i] === someString[i - 1] then the characters are repeating, if someString[i] !== someString[i - 1] then they are not repeating, so you return someString[i]

I won't write the whole thing out for you, but hopefully the thought process behind this will help

Comment: That only checks if it repeats the character before it.  His example shows it can repeat anywhere - `abcdea` has a repeating `a`

Comment: Thank you for understanding what I was asking Dave.  Thank you for answering anyway Martin

Answer (score 1):

```
 function FirstNotRepeatedChar(str) {
 var arr = str.split('');
 var result = '';
 var ctr = 0; 
  for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
   ctr = 0;
  for (var y = 0; y < arr.length; y++) {
  if (arr[x] === arr[y]) {
    ctr+= 1;
    }
   }

if (ctr < 2) {
  result = arr[x];
  break;
  }
}
return result;
}
console.log(FirstNotRepeatedChar('asif shaik'));
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.   Rather than posting a comment under your answer, edit your question to provide all of your advice in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an O(n) solution with 2 ES6 Sets, one tracking all characters that have appeared and one tracking only chars that have appeared once. This solution takes advantage of the insertion order preserved by Set.

```
const firstNonRepeating = str => {
  const set = new Set();
  const finalSet = new Set();
  str.split('').forEach(char => {
    if (set.has(char)) finalSet.delete(char);
    else {
      set.add(char);
      finalSet.add(char);
    }
  })
  const iter = finalSet.values();
  return iter.next().value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr = [10, 5, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6];
outer:for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    for(let j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
        if(arr[i]===arr[j+1]){
            console.log(arr[i]);
            break outer;
        }
    }
}


//or else you may try this way...
function firstDuplicate(arr) {
    let findFirst = new Set()
    for (element of arr)
        if (findFirst.has(element ))
            return element 
        else
            findFirst.add(element )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function firstUniqChar(str) {
    let myMap = new Map();
    for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        let char = str.charAt(i);
        if(!myMap.has(char)) {
            myMap.set(char, 0);
        }
        myMap.set(char, myMap.get(char) + 1 );
    }
    for(let [key, value] of myMap) {
       if(value === 1) {
           return key;
       }
    }
    return null;
}

let result = firstUniqChar("caabbdccee");
console.log(result);
```

You can use Map Object and set key and value, where in value you store the count for that particular character, After that you can iterate over map and check where is value 1 and return that key.

> Map Object remembers the original insertion order of the keys.

Answer (score 1):

This solution should works with array with integers and string.

```
function firstNoneRepeating(list, map = new Map()) {
  for (let item of list) {
    if (map.has(item)) {
      map.set(item, map.get(item) + 1);
    } else {
      map.set(item, 1);
    }
  }
  for (let [key, value] of map.entries()) {
    if (value === 1) {
      return key;
    }
  }
}
console.log(firstNoneRepeating("aabcbd"));
console.log(firstNoneRepeating([5, 2, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 1):

We can keep track of frequency of each character of the string in an object.
For example : for "aabcbd" we can store the frequency as

> { "a":2, "b":2, "c":1, "d":1 }

This will take O(n) time.
Then we can traverse over this object and find the first character with frequency 1, which will also take O(n) time. So, the time complexity for this approach will be O(n).

```
const firstNonRepeating=(str)=>{
const obj={};
str.split("").forEach(item=>{
  obj[item] 
  ? obj[item]++ 
  : obj[item]=1;
});
const item = Object.keys(obj).find(key=> obj[key] === 1);
return item;
}
```

> Note: I use ES6 Object.keys method which may not work in older
>   browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
let str='aabcbd'
let ans=''
for (let i=0;i<str.length;i++){
    if(str.indexOf(str.charAt(i))===str.lastIndexOf(str.charAt(i))){
    ans+=str.charAt(i)
    break
    }
}
console.log(ans)
```

Comment: Odd choice to use `charAt` instead of `[]` these days. Are you running IE 7 or 8? Also, why concatenate the character instead of just assigning?

Answer (score 0):

Fill an empty array with zeros, with same length as the string array, and tally up how many times they appear through the loop. Grab the first one in the tallied array with a value of 1.

```
function firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s) {
    const array = s.split("");
    let scores = new Array(array.length).fill(0);

    for (let char of array) {
        scores[array.indexOf(char)]++;
    }

    const singleChar = array[scores.indexOf(1)];
    return singleChar ? singleChar : "_"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each character to [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the first letter that returns a single [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). This will result in the first non-repeated character in the given string:

```js
const first_nonrepeated_character = string => [...string].find(e => string.match(new RegExp(e, 'g')).length === 1);
const string = 'aabcbd';

console.log(first_nonrepeated_character(string)); // c
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution which have time complexity of o(n)

```
function getfirstNonRepeatingCharacterInAString(params) {
    let count = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        let count1 = 0;
        if (!count[params.charAt(i)]) {
            count[params.charAt(i)] = count1 + 1;
        }
        else {
            count[params.charAt(i)] = count[params.charAt(i)] + 1;
        }
    }
    for (let key in count) {
        if (count[key] === 1) {
            return key;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
console.log(getfirstNonRepeatingCharacterInAString("GeeksfoGeeks"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using forEach and convert the string into an array

```
function firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s) {
    var strArr = s.split("");
    var found = "_";
    strArr.forEach(function(item, index) {
        if (strArr.indexOf(item) == index && strArr.indexOf(item, index + 1) == -1) {
            if (found === "_") {
                found = item;
            }
        }
    })

    return found;
}

firstNotRepeatingCharacter("abacabad")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

Everytime you find equal chars store it in an array and break out of the loop. If the char is not found in the array then you have your first nonRepeating char

```js
function nonRepeatingChars(value) {
  const memory = []
  for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < value.length; j++) {
      if (value[i] === value[j]) {
        memory.push(value[j])
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!memory.some(x => x === value[i])) {
      return value[i];
    }
  }
  return "all chars have duplicates";
}

console.log('First non repeating char is:',nonRepeatingChars("esen"))
console.log('First non repeating char is:',nonRepeatingChars("esesn"))
console.log('First non repeating char is:',nonRepeatingChars("eseulsn"))
console.log('First non repeating char is:',nonRepeatingChars("esesnn"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> var firstNonRepeatedCharacter = function (str){   
> for(i=0;i<str.length;i++){
>     if(str.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) === str.lastIndexOf(str.charAt(i))){
>       console.log(str.charAt(i));
>       break;
>     }   } }
> 
> firstNonRepeatedCharacter ("areerak");
```

you can check below link

https://codepen.io/t3veni/pen/wvvxJzm

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to solve this algorithm, very straight forward.

```
function firstNonRepeatChar(str){
    let map = {};
    for(let i=0; i<str.length; i++){
        if(Object.keys(map).includes(str[i])){
            map[str[i]]++
        }
        else{
            map[str[i]] = 1;
        }
    }

    for(let j=0; j< Object.values(map).length; j++){
        if(Object.values(map)[j] == 1){
            console.log(Object.keys(map)[j]);
            return
        }
        if (j == Object.values(map).length-1 && Object.values(map)[j] != 1){
            console.log('_');
            return;
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }
}

nonRepeat("aaabbcccdeeef");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one other solution just using array, using 26 unique character as length of array:

```js
var firstUniqChar = (function(s) {
    var arr = [];
    var str = s.toLowerCase();
    for(let c of str){
      let index = c.charCodeAt(0) - "a".charCodeAt(0);
      arr[index]? ++arr[index]: arr[index]=1;
    }
    
    for(let c of str){
      let index = c.charCodeAt(0) - 97;
      if(arr[index] == 1){
        return c;
      };
    }

    return -1;
}("aabcbd"));

console.log(firstUniqChar);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //To find first non repeating letter 
    //It will check for both upper and lower case
    //only use one String.indexOf()

    var mystr="ohvhvtccggt";
    var checkFirstNonRepeating=function(){
    var ele=[];
      for(var i=0;i<mystr.length;i++) {
      var key=mystr.charAt(i);
      if(!ele[key])
          ele[key]=0;
      ele[key]++;

   //Just check for second occurance of character 
   //no need to use indexOf twice

       if(mystr.indexOf(key,i+1)==-1 && ele[key]<2)  
         return mystr[i];
       }
     return "All repeating letters";
    }
    console.log(checkFirstNonRepeating());
              
        /*
        Input  : "ohvhvtoccggt"
        Output : All repeating letters
        Input  :"oohjtht"
        Output :j 
        */
```

Answer (score 0):

I used object to keep track of characters count in a string then return the char that has the fa value of 1. Here is a demo:

```js
function firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s) {

// initialize an empty object to store chars

    let seen = {};
    let letter = '';

  // iterate over each char in a string
  // if it is already there increase value by one
  // else set the value to 1

    for(let char of s){
            if (seen[char]){
                    seen[char] +=1;
            } else {
                    seen[char] = 1;
            }
    }

  // iterate over the new constructed object
  // if the value is 1 and the output variable is empty
  // return the associated key to the value 1
  // else return '_'

    for(let v in seen){
        while(seen[v] == 1 && letter === ''){
            letter += v;
            return letter;
        } 
    }
return('_');
}

console.log(firstNotRepeatingCharacter("abacabad"));
console.log(firstNotRepeatingCharacter("cbc"));
console.log(firstNotRepeatingCharacter("bcccccccccccccyb"));
console.log(firstNotRepeatingCharacter("aaa"));
```

Comment: I don't think this will work if the non-repeating char is coming in non-alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

The most satisfactory and easy to understand answer is the following.

```
function firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s) {
        
    const arr = s.split("");

    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        let chr = arr[i];
        if( arr.indexOf(arr[i]) == arr.lastIndexOf(arr[i])){
            return arr[i]
        }            
    }
    
    return "_"
}
```

Explanation: It loops through all the characters of a string from forward and backward and then compares the values. If the index of both forward and backward search is true then it returns that character.

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = 'aabbcdd';
let val = str.split('').reduce((a, e)=>{ if(str.indexOf(e) == str.lastIndexOf(e)) {a = e }; return a})
console.log(val); // c
```

Answer (score 0):

the implementation below has a good time complexity and it accounts for letters with different cases:

steps
must touch every character in the string to know if it's repeated or not

````
function firstNonRepeatingLetter(wordd) {

    const chars = {}

    let word = wordd.toLowerCase()

    // go through chars
    // store chars in hash with values of array storing index of char and true if only 1 encountered so far
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i += 1) {
        let char = word[i]
        if (chars[char]) {
            chars[char][0] = false
        } else {
            chars[char] = [true, i]
        }
    }
    let output = ''
    let index;
    for (let key in chars) {
    // return char with true and lowest index
        if (chars[key][0]) {
            index = index === undefined ? chars[key][1] : index
            if (index >= chars[key][1]) {
                output = key
            }
        }
    }
    return index === undefined ? '' : wordd[index]
}
console.log(firstNonRepeatingLetter('sTreSS')) //T```
````

Answer (score 0):

The bellow solution is a kind of frequency counter pattern and it will run only one loop, so O(n) will be the time complexity.

```
function firstNotRepeatingCharacter(str) {
  const obj = {};
  for (let i = 0, L = str.length; i < L; i++) {
    const char = str[i];
    obj[char] = obj[char] ? obj[char] + 1 : 1;
  }

  for (let key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    if (obj[key] == 1) {
      return key;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution

```
function firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s) {

     const obj = {};

      for (let i of s) {
        if(!obj[i]) {
            obj[i] = 1;
        } else if (obj[i]) {
            obj[i] = +obj[i] + 1;
        }
      }
    
      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if(value == 1) return key;
      }
    
    return "_"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using below method can achieve first non repeated character

```js
function main(str) {
    str = String(str).toLowerCase();
    let non_repeated_char = 'N/A';
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        let currentChar = str[i];
        let repeated_times = String(str).split('').filter(e => e == currentChar).length;
        if (repeated_times === 1) {
            non_repeated_char = currentChar;
            break;
        }
    }
    return non_repeated_char;
};

let Result = main("basketball");
console.log("The Non Repeated char is-->", Result);
```

Answer (score -1):

**If any one looking for one-line solution n ES6**

```js
const firstUniqueChar = (str) =>str.split('').map(item => str.indexOf(item) === str.lastIndexOf(item) ? item : '').filter(item => !!item)[0]

console.log(firstUniqueChar('aacddx'))
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried to achieve same without using indexof or lastindexof.

```
function findfirst(str){
  let chararr = str.split("");
  let uniq = [];
  let obj = new Map();
  for(let i=0;i<chararr.length;i++){
    if(obj.get(chararr[i])){
      obj.set(chararr[i], false);
    }
    else{
      obj.set(chararr[i],true);
    }
  }
  
obj.forEach((v,k) => {if(v){uniq.push(k);}})
return uniq[0]
}
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.